# How to pronounce "×"?

Tags: pronunciation, symbols

The symbol × is sometimes used in titles like **「ラビ×ラビ -パズルアウトストーリーズ-」** or headlines like this one: **「スシロー×寿司ストライカー スペシャルキャンペーン」**.

I imagine native speakers who read it might pronounce it as と, since it seems to mean "and", like in the above example of a game with two characters and a joint campaign.

How is the symbol actually pronounced?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This type of `×` (indicates a close relationship between two things/people) is usually simply ignored, just as we do not bother to read ❤ or ★ aloud in titles and such. "ラビ×ラビ" is read as ラビラビ as if it were one word. "スシロー×寿司ストライカー" would be pronounced with a small pause between スシロー and 寿司ストライカー.

Similar examples from real manga titles:

> - [HUNTER × HUNTER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter)　（pronounced as ハンターハンター）
> - [サーバント × サービス](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_%C3%97_Service)　（pronounced as サーバントサービス）
> - [ノゾ × キミ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8E%E3%82%BE%C3%97%E3%82%AD%E3%83%9F)　（pronounced as [ノゾキミ](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A6%97%E3%81%8D%E8%A6%8B)）

When you *must* read this symbol aloud (e.g., when you need to tell the "spelling" of this title over the phone), you can read it as かける or バツ.

Comment: Sounds like it resembles a slash that's sometimes used in English, as in "and/or"

Comment: @waldrumpus Yes, and Japanese `×` resembles English slash in that they can signify a close (romantic) relationship between two people (often of the same sex) :)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility, depending on the context/title, is "cross" (「クロス」).

- [Street Fighter × Tekken　→　ストリートファイター**クロス**鉄拳](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Street_Fighter_%C3%97_Tekken)
- [Street Fighter × Rockman　→　ストリートファイター**クロス**ロックマン](http://megaman.wikia.com/wiki/Street_Fighter_X_Mega_Man)
- [Namco × Capcom　→　ナムコ**クロス**カプコン](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Namco_%C3%97_Capcom)

These all happen to be video games, so I don't know if this reading carries over to other things/areas/media.

Comment: I think the クロス reading pertains to whenever two sources of media perform a cross-over and are joined together (as OP was saying, as if it were an "and")